# cocos2d loaded size and total size during scene transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, progress-bar

I'm doing a progress bar to show the current progress during transition time from scene 1 -> scene 2
simply my progress bar value will base on current loaded resource size and total resource size needed to load scene 2 
But I don't know how to get these 2 values. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a "resource size" to you?

If you consider an image file, then that image file has a size on disk which may or may not be compressed, with compression depending on file content. The image file gets loaded into a texture, which has an in-memory size. That too may be compressed (PVR) or not. Finally, the size of an image on disk, the compression, and the memory representation (bit depth etc) all factor into how long it takes to load that image.

If you extend that to other resource types like sound files, property lists, databases it gets extremely difficult to control a progress bar based on some arbitrary, hard to define "resource size".

Long story short: you can get a file's size. You can base your loading bar on that but it won't reflect the actual loading time at all.

You can also estimate or calculate the amount of memory a resource takes up, ie a 2048x2048x32bit texture is 16 MB - unless it is compressed even in memory (PVR textures). But this requires intimate knowledge of each asset's data structure. Plus, for example if you only load four of these textures your progress bar will jump to 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% after each texture - you have no way of knowing  "how far into loading the texture" the device is to make the progressbar progress smoothly in such cases.

**Long story short:**

Most progress bars simply consider **how many** resources are being loaded. This you know from the code you put into the scene, ie. which images, audio files, etc. you load. Unless you load your entire scene from a data file, for example if you use some kind of design tool, you won't know the number of resources at runtime until after they're loaded.

An alternative is to update your progress bar after each block of resources, so that you can divide the progressbar progress into few, concrete steps. This is particularly helpful if few resources take most of the time to load, and they are atomic chunks (ie 2048x2048 texture atlas) which take several fractions of a second to load without any chance of updating the progress bar.

Finally, unless you actually see a loading time of 3+ seconds a progressbar makes little sense. In that case you may better spend your time on optimizing loading times. For example a lot can be done by choosing the ideal texture format, by using texture atlases, by avoiding redundant asset loads, by deferring loading of certain assets or loading them in a separate thread.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, I figured out how to do it from your advices.